# Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' in Spring with Java EE dependencies

Tags: java, spring, jpa, intellij-idea, jakarta-ee

I've tried to add dependencies to another repository. My project is in Spring and I wanted to add a dependency to Java EE project with mappings. Can this be a problem?

I have seen similar problems, but the additional logs are showing different problem than just lack of hibernate dependency or wrong synthax.

Error message:

```
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The resource path [/..] has been normalized to [null] which is not valid
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1796) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1108) ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868) ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) [spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) [spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at com.edocs.zbiksoft.EdocsApplication.main(EdocsApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The resource path [/..] has been normalized to [null] which is not valid
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.validate(StandardRoot.java:267) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.getResource(StandardRoot.java:213) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.getResource(StandardRoot.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.getResource(ApplicationContext.java:538) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContextFacade.getResource(ApplicationContextFacade.java:200) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource.exists(ServletContextResource.java:104) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.PersistenceUnitReader.parseJarFiles(PersistenceUnitReader.java:310) ~[spring-orm-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.PersistenceUnitReader.parsePersistenceUnitInfo(PersistenceUnitReader.java:252) ~[spring-orm-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.PersistenceUnitReader.parseDocument(PersistenceUnitReader.java:184) ~[spring-orm-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.PersistenceUnitReader.readPersistenceUnitInfos(PersistenceUnitReader.java:136) ~[spring-orm-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.readPersistenceUnitInfos(DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.java:507) ~[spring-orm-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.preparePersistenceUnitInfos(DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.java:460) ~[spring-orm-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.afterPropertiesSet(DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.java:444) ~[spring-orm-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:328) ~[spring-orm-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1855) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1792) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
```

My pom.xml repositories tag:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>id name</id>
        <name>Repository name</name>
        <url>http://path/to//repositories/public/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>id name</id>
        <name>Repository name</name>
        <url>http://path/to//repositories/public/</url>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>
```

SpringBoot version 2.2.2

```
SpringBoot main class
@SpringBootApplication
public class MainClass{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MainClass.class, args);
    }

}
```

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/database-name
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The resource path [/..] has been normalized to [null] which is not valid

Comment: What does it mean? Can the URL to repository be wrong?

Comment: What SpringBoot version do you use? Could you please provide your Spring run configuration?

Comment: updated description